# How to configure dynamic subdomains pointing to each node of an autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an autoscaling group with N nodes in it. Quite often nodes will be killed/added, and whenever a new node is added I need to assign a subdomain to it:

Eg: node http://ec2-18-230-57-233.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com can be accessed via http://ec2-18-230-57-233.mydomain.com (or any other randomly generated subdomain)

How can I accomplish this using whatever tools available on AWS?

Comment: Does your DNS service provider have an API for create/update DNS records in a hosted zone on the fly?  For example if you use Route53, you can use AWS CLI or SDK to do it programmatically.

Comment: How about [ASG Lifecycle Hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) -> SQS -> Lambda -> Update Route 53

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I have no choice other then using cloudwatch to call lambda functions to update the dns records